# Fabric run() output is dirt

Tags: python, fabric

When I use:

```
out = run("ls")
```

I want in "out" list of files. But, I also get trash. How to get only out of the shell command?

```
$ fab -p 111 -H server func
[server] Executing task 'func'
[server] run: ls
[server] out:
[server] out:
[server] out: MQSI 9.0.0.3
[server] out: /opt/IBM/mqsi/9.0.0.3
[server] out:
[server] out: /var/mqsi/odbc/odbc64.ini
[server] out: file1 file2 file3
[server] out:

MQSI 9.0.0.3
/opt/IBM/mqsi/9.0.0.3

/var/mqsi/odbc/odbc64.ini
file1 file2 file3
```

So in `out` i get all text from `MQSI` to `file3`. But I need only `file1 file2 file3`

Probably it is not fabric fault. Maybe something with server shell.

I very tried use different fabric hiding, but didn't find the answer.

Comment: How do you mean "get trash" ?

Comment: @joeb i modified answer. Under trash i mean 
               MQSI 9.0.0.3
                /opt/IBM/mqsi/9.0.0.3 

                /var/mqsi/odbc/odbc64.ini

Comment: Now i see only one way to avoid such problem.  Use `out = run("echo 'start' && ls")        out=out[ out.index('start')+1: ]`

Comment: But that doesnt look good as for me

Comment: Go take a look at the flags available to "ls" and the "find" commands.

Comment: What's the output if you run 'ls' on the server? And if you run '/bin/bash -l -c "ls"' (this is what fabric runs by default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, by "trash" you're referring to the "\t", "\r", and "\n" characters that are present in the output of the `ls` command. An example I just generated looks like this:

```
>>>> out = run('ls')
>>>> print(out)
'nginx\t\t\t\tnginx.bak.20151206-2209.tar.gz\tnginx.bak.20151206-2258.tar.gz\tphp-fpm.conf.save\r\nnginx.bak.20151206-2047.tar.gz\r\nnginx.bak.20151206-2153.tar.gz\tnginx.bak.20151206-2226.tar.gz\tphp-fpm.conf\t\t\tsupervisord.conf\r\nnginx.bak.20151206-2206.tar.gz\tnginx.bak.20151206-2255.tar.gz\tphp-fpm.conf.default\t\tvarnish'
```

To turn that into a list, you can `.split()` it, like:

```
>>> out.split()
['nginx', 'nginx.bak.20151206-2209.tar.gz', 'nginx.bak.20151206-2258.tar.gz', 'php-fpm.conf.save', 'nginx.bak.20151206-2047.tar.gz', 'nginx.bak.20151206-2153.tar.gz', 'nginx.bak.20151206-2226.tar.gz', 'php-fpm.conf', 'supervisord.conf', 'nginx.bak.20151206-2206.tar.gz', 'nginx.bak.20151206-2255.tar.gz', 'php-fpm.conf.default', 'varnish']
```

Comment: I dont need the text from the shell , except out of `ls`. In my case , firstly shell return some excess information.